# How to call a view with a specific size?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a question about views in swiftui.

I have created a file CircleView which shows me a circle and a text in the middle. Additionally I have created a list in ContentView and a DetailView for details.
I now use the created circle in the list and on the detail view. Unfortunately the size of the circle is defined in the CircleView and I don't know how to change it individually so that it is displayed small in the list and uses the full width on the detail view.
So how can I change the size of a view individually?

Here is my code

CircleView:

```
struct CircleView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
        Text("VIEW")
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
  }
}
```

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List{
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView()) {
                  HStack{
                    Text("Hello")
                    Spacer()
                    CircleView()
                  }
                }.navigationTitle("Home")     
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

DetailsView:

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .padding(10)
            CircleView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a couple of options here. 1) take the frame out of circleView and define it in contentView and detailView as a modifier to CircleView(). Or 2) create a width and height variable within your CircleView struct with a default value (e.g 250 and 250) and then pass in an alternative value whenever you wish to not use the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the set frame from your view and apply it when using your view.

Your code edited:

```
struct Sample: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView()) {
                    HStack{
                        Text("Hello")
                        Spacer()
                        CircleView()
                            .frame(width: 100 , height: 100) // <-- Update frame here
                    }
                }.navigationTitle("Home")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
            Text("VIEW")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}

struct Sample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Sample()
    }
}


struct DetailsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .padding(10)
            CircleView().padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works wonderful